# Mock an Exception in phpUnit

Tags: php, mocking, phpunit

The method I am trying to test has a try catch like

```
try {
    $fooClass->doStuff(); // Throws \Lib\Custom\Exception
} 
catch (\Lib\Custom\Exception $exception) {
    return false;
}
```

I want to test if the return is false, but the custom exception is not loaded when my tests are executed.

Php unit has the option of mocking classes, but I can't seem to use this for Exceptions.

```
$exceptionMock= $this->getMockBuilder(\Lib\Custom\Exception::class)->getMock();

$fooClassMock = $this->getMockBuilder(fooClass::class)->getMock()
     ->method('doStuff')
     ->willThrowException($exceptionMock);
```

Gives me the folowing exception:

```
Argument 1 passed to 
PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_Builder_InvocationMocker::willThrowException() 
must be an instance of Exception, instance of Mock_Exception_c4dd9394 given
```

How to properly mock this Exception to test the function?

Comment: does your `\Lib\Custom\Exception` extend `\Exception` ?

Comment: Yes it does, but it is not in the composer.json autoload.

Comment: so when the mock is created it appears not to be a child of `\Exception`.

Comment: Yeah, the mock is not a type of exception. This may be a good addition to the phpUnit mocking someday. But for now I'll add the lib to my autoloader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that your test isn't working is because the class isn't known in the test.  When that happens and you create a mock in PHPUnit, it does some trickery to create a class definition and then extends that to create the mock.  Otherwise it would use the extend the class itself and you would not have had a problem.

In this case, PHPUnit creates a fake `\Lib\Custom\Exception` and then uses that to create the mock.  The fake class created doesn't extend anything (since it wouldn't know what to extend/implement).  So the type hint in the `willThrowException` will not be matched because your mock object didn't extend `Exception`.

This would happen with any type hinting for extended classes in PHPUnit if the class is not loaded in the test.  In order to fix this, you need to have the class available in the test via a require, include, or autoloader.

Comment: Yeah this is the answer. I have now loaded it and it works properly. And saves me a whole lot of code for mocking the lib classes.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you need to mock the exception.

why not try this?

```
$fooClassMock = $this->getMockBuilder(fooClass::class)->getMock()
     ->method('doStuff')
     ->willThrowException(new \Lib\Custom\Exception());
```

Or something similar..

Comment: Because the `\Lib\Custom\Exception()` is not known while running the tests, so it will give a `Class 'Twizo\Api\Entity\Exception' not found` error.

Comment: well, if its not known, it will not be either mocked, nor simply used..
you need to edit the path to it, so it will be known. after you do that, i still suggest that you just use it and not mock it.

Comment: Okay, I was affraid this might be the only sollution. 
I will include it in my autoload. :/
Thanks for your help!

Comment: i am not familiar with your project infrastructure.. but maybe you do not have to include it in autoload, because this will affect all of this autoload users (pages).
you can perhaps require or include it in this specific test page..

Comment: Why not have your tests use the same autoloader as the rest of your codebase? It seems like a lot of work to have to autoload individual files when you want to test them.

Comment: I do not include it because the main code is autoloaded via Joomla!'s autoload framwork wrapper. And is by that reason only loaded when the whole joomla system is active. 

The tests have a seperare composer instance because composer is not supported in Joomla! 3.8

Comment: can u load manually as a single include\require? @YarinceMartis

Comment: I have now included in my autoload, it's easier that way. And solved the problem. I don't know why I didn't do that from the start.